# What a SDR can (and cannot) tell about a received signal's power/energy

Tags: power-spectral-density, signal-power, software-defined-radio, measurement

I'm rather new to SDR and I'm still wrapping my head around understanding how it functions. I greatly appreciate it if you guys can help me understand what's going on.

From what I've gathered, an SDR is not an instrument capable of measuring a signal's power/energy and it needs some specific calibration to correctly measure power/energy. Is that true? If that's the case, what exactly am I seeing when I display the signal in a spectrum analyzer (in terms of amplitude)? I can see the signal apart from the noise, so there's an SNR (which never seems to make sense). How did the SDR produce a signal SNR exactly? And if there are 2 signals with 2 different receiving power, would the ratio between the 2 SNRs be correct or not? Will I get the correct power spectrum density with an SDR if I use DFT?

Again, I'm new so I might get everything wrong, so please feel free to correct me. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I've gathered, an SDR is not an instrument capable of measuring a signal's power/energy and it needs some specific calibration to correctly measure power/energy. Is that true?

Hm. somewhat true: an SDR is not necessarily calibrated. There are calibrated SDRs. But, for usage as communications device, you don't need that, so it's not usually something that an SDR does.

All any SDR guarantees for it's linear range is that the digital amplitudes are *proportional* to the observed physical quantities. There's simply an unknown, constant factor between physical amplitude (say, field strength in volts per meter) and the digital values (which are unitless). So,

$$q_{\text{digital}} = c\cdot q_{\text{analog}},$$

where $c$ is a factor whose unit is inverse to the unit of the analog quantity, and should be constant (but depend on things like gain and center frequency, and to a lesser extent, temperature etc).

> How did the SDR produce a signal SNR exactly?

It doesn't. SNR is a function of what *you* / *your* application define as *signal*, and as *noise*. There's no "SNR in general": One receiver's noise is another receiver's signal.

> And if there are 2 signals with 2 different receiving power, would the ratio between the 2 SNRs be correct or not?

This sentence sadly makes no sense. What does "correct" even mean in this context?

But if you're operating the SDR in its linear range (i.e. not overdriving it, or underamplifying), then yes, since digital amplitude is proportional to physical amplitude, power ratios in the analog domain and the digital domain are identical.

> Will I get the correct power spectrum density with an SDR if I use DFT?

You get something that *estimates* a PSD that is *proportional* to the analog signal's PSD. (you cannot "get" a PSD from a signal. It's a hidden stochastic property. You can only *estimate* it. And since an SDR in its linear range gives digital values that are proportional to the physical amplitude within the observable bandwidth, the PSDs estimate is best-case proportional to the signal's PSD.)

---

Especially in the hobbyist radio operators community, the fact that communication engineers never actually care about the actual received power really confuses a lot of people. Honestly, I'm a bit tired explaining to people that their S-meter is the least useful tool in their ham shack! But it is simply like that; for your ability to extract information from a signal, it's never relevant what the actual amplitude (or power) of the signal is. If I think it's too low, I can just multiply it with 1000, or a million or any number, losslessly! What matters is how much noise is in there *relative* to the signal, i.e. the SNR. And because it's like that, receivers like SDRs do not compete via calibration, which is out of their control, anyways, but about how much noise they add to the reception (their *noise figure*).

Comment: Ah I see, so it lies in the fact that SDR deals with the digitalized version of the signal, not the analog directly. It's pretty interesting that the actually received power isn't needed in DSP.
And sorry for the bad wording about SNR. I just meant we are supposed to know both the energy of noise and signal. The 2 SNR one meant if the ratio of 2 received signal power stays true in the reading provided by SDR, which I assume to be the case if the SDR encodes the amplitude in a linear matter. However, I can see how the actual received power doesn't matter.
Thank you so much for your answer!